# How do I use group_by in r to combine rows of a dataframe by some columns, but keep other columns as well

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

This should be simple, I just can't get it to work

I have a dataframe `all_emissions_state_total` that looks something like this:

```
tribe    state      scc       pollutant      emissions     unit     category    eis     year     fraction 
NA       WY         707       Methane        546           TON      onroad      NA      2011     NA
NA       WY         707       Methane        38            TON      onroad      NA      2011     NA
NA       WY         3405      Methane        2937          TON      onroad      NA      2011     NA
NA       MT         707       Methane        665           TON      onroad      NA      2011     NA
NA       WY         390       CO2            740           TON      onroad      NA      2011     NA
NA       MT         390       CO2            12            TON      onroad      NA      2011     NA
NA       WY         3405      Methane        329           TON      onroad      NA      2011     NA
GHYU     WY         390       CO2            44            TON      point       NA      2011     NA
BERS     WY         390       CO2            64445         TON      point       NA      2011     596
SDSH     KS         707       Methane        123           TON      point       NA      2011     3890
SDSH     MT         707       Methane        58            TON      point       NA      2011     112
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
state       scc        pollutant        emissions        unit        year
WY          707        Methane          584              TON         2011
MT          707        Methane          723              TON         2011
WY          3405       Methane          3266             TON         2011
WY          390        CO2              65229            TON         2011
MT          390        CO2              12               TON         2011
KS          707        Methane          123              TON         2011
```

In the original dataframe `all_emissions_state_total`, `tribe`, `state`, `scc`, `pollutant`, `emissions`, `category`, `eis`, and `fraction` vary. `unit` is always TON, and `year` is always 2011.

I am wanting the rows to be grouped by rows that have the same `state`, `scc`, and `pollutant`, and for the `emissions` column to be the sum of those rows that are being grouped. `tribe`, `category`, `eis`, and `fraction` do not matter and can be dropped, but `unit` and `year` need to stay.

This is what I thought would work:

```
all_emissions_state <- all_emissions_state_total %>%
                                group_by( state, scc, pollutant ) %>% 
                                summarise( emissions = sum( emissions ) )
```

but my output for this is a 1x1 dataframe `all_emissions_state` that has column `emissions` and 1 value that is the sum of all emissions from the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option in Base

```
    New_df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, with(df,paste0(state,scc,pollutant))), function(x) x[1,c("state","scc","pollutant","emissions","unit","year")]))
    New_df$emissions <- sapply( split(df$emissions, with(df,paste0(state,scc,pollutant))), sum)
    row.names(New_df) <- NULL

> New_df
  state  scc pollutant emissions unit year
1    KS  707   Methane       123  TON 2011
2    MT  390       CO2        12  TON 2011
3    MT  707   Methane       723  TON 2011
4    WY 3405   Methane      3266  TON 2011
5    WY  390       CO2     65229  TON 2011
6    WY  707   Methane       584  TON 2011
```

Comment: This is helpful, but would prefer to use a method that can work no matter the order of the columns

Comment: @MarideeWeber Simple fix, I've swapped out the index for column names

Answer (score 0):

This should work if unit/year are constant across group. Try putting dplyr::sumarise() maybe you have function conflict.

```
all_emissions_state <- all_emissions_state_total %>%
      dplyr::group_by(state, scc, pollutant) %>% 
      dplyr::summarise( 
         emissions = sum(emissions),
         unit = dplyr::first(unit),
         year = dplyr::first(year)
    )
```